# problems with jquery $.get

Tags: jquery

It is not first time I use `$.get` function, but this time I dont know why it is not working

```
function test(tid)
  {
    alert("1");
   var ttt;
   alert("2");
   var ddd;
    alert("3");

   $.get("demo_ajax_load.txt", function(result){
    alert("4");
     });
   }
```

`demo_ajax_load.txt` is just a text file content is: `Welcome`

I am getting alert 1,2,3 but it is not showing 4th alert message. everything looks normal here, what is wrong with this simple function?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Open the Network tab in Chrome, check the demo_ajax_load.txt request and give us the status.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ The 4th alert will only occur if the ajax call succeeded. Apparently it does not.

Comment: Make sure that the file demo_ajax_load.txt has the right path

Comment: I checked Network Tab, but couldnt find anything related to demo_ajax_load.txt

Comment: have you tried renaming the .txt file to another file format? like 'html' ?  Maybe a datatype issue, but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Check for any errors: $.get("...").error(function() { alert("error"); });

Comment: It can also be a local security network issue. Have you tried to run it on a server instead of the file system (like on IIS or Apache) Using an http address?

Comment: I am running it on server, not on my local. I wanted to use php file, but I thought I have errors on my php file, just wanted to test it with simple example, like calling a text file, but it is not working either. ok let me try to alert error

Comment: .error(function() {
       alert('woops'); // or whatever
       });    it is not showing alert either

Comment: @SamirMemmedov OK, maybe you didn't include jQuery library?

Comment: I checked it with this : if (jQuery) {  
    alert("ok");
} else {
   alert("not ok ");
}  I am getting ok message . I have included it. maybe wrong version ? how to link to latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

It will probably have nothing wrong as long as you are not testing it locally.

if you're using **Google Chrome** *(I'm using version 20)*, open the console (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and you will see that you will get an error:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

[image]

in **Mozilla Firefox**, you will get

> [object XMLDocument]

but if you do this remotely (in your host), everything will get working normally...

you can see my [**Live DEMO**](http://balexandre.com/Stackoverflow/11335668/) and open the console to see the output if you like.

my simple jQuery:

```
$.when(
    $.get("a.txt")
  )
 .done(function(data) { 
    console.log("All done: " + data); 
    $(".txt-from-file").text(data); 
  })
 .fail(function(data) { 
    console.log("Error found: " + data.statusText); 
    $(".txt-from-file").text(data.statusText); 
  });
```

or you can always simplify more and use:

```
$.get("a.txt").then(
    function() { alert("succeeded"); },
    function() { alert("failed!"); }
);
```

Comment: I have aded console.log commands, tryed it on chrome, pressed F12, it showed me js script code, I didnt get any error

Comment: and I am doing it on server, I am on dedicated web server

Comment: Sorry , wait, let me look at console, I mis looked before

Comment: I am having bunch of errors :  1- cant open css not important I think 2- mischandler is not defined index.php:735
3-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) swfobject_modified.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object function $(element) {

  if (arguments.length > 1) {

    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)

      elements.push($(arguments[i]));

    return elements;

  }

  if (Object.isString(element))

    element = document.getElementById(element);

  return Element.extend(element);

} has no method 'get' countdown.js:7

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks for trying to help me , I found solution, I should use jQuery instead of $ , and it worked